# Quasifibrations and homotopy pullbacks

Tags: homotopy-theory, at.algebraic-topology

I'm wondering about the theoretical placement of quasifibrations.

One nice thing about "weak fibrations" (maps homotopy equivalent in the category of maps to Hurewicz fibrations) is that a pullback square involving (one) weak fibration is a homotopy pullback square.

Is the corresponding result 
 true for quasifibrations in the Serre-Quillen context?  That is, suppose $E\to B$
is a quasifibration, and the square
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
P & \to & E
\cr\downarrow&pb&\downarrow
\cr
X& \to &B
\end{array}
$$
is a categorical pullback.  Then is it a homotopy pullback in the Quillen-Serre model
structure?

Comment: Dold and Lashof compare their construction for a monoid M to Milnor's
when M is a group G. They give an explicit comparison for the first stage of the constructions. Somewhere I've seen the general n-stage comparison formula - anyone remember where?

Comment: The desired formula can be produced by careful iteration of the case given by Dold&Lashof. It also appears in Peter May's Geometry of iterated loop spaces pp.98-99 without mention of Dold&Lashof.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The definition of quasifibration (according to Dold & Thom, 1958) is: a map $f:E\to B$ such that for all $b$ in $B$, the canonical map from the fiber to the homotopy fiber is a weak equivalence.  Pullbacks with respect to such maps are *not* generally homotopy pullbacks; an example was given in that 1958 paper (Bermerkung 2.3), which goes something like this:

Let $\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}B=\R\times \R$.  Then $E$ will have the same underlying set as $B$, and $f$ will be the identity map.  But we topologize $E$ by "tearing" along the positive $y$-axis.  For instance, let $E$ have the smallest topology such that $f$ is continuous *and* the set $[0,\infty)\times (0,\infty)$ is open.

The space $E$ is still contractible with this topology (it deformation retracts to $\R\times -1$).  Therefore, the homotopy fiber over any point of $B$ must be weakly contractible, and thus weakly equivalent to the actual one-point fiber.  So $f$ is a quasi-fibration.

Let $X= \mathbb{R}\times 1\subset B$, and let $P$ be the pullback of $E$ over $X$.  Then $P$ has two path components, while $X$ is contractible; this is not a homotopy pullback!

Comment: This answers my question, and makes me wish I could read German much more quickly.

Answer (score 12):

It rather depends what you mean by quasi-fibration. The most useful resource I know for questions about quasi-fibrations is [this](http://www.lehigh.edu/~dmd1/tg516.txt) message of Goodwillie, posted to the APGTOP mailing list in 2001.

Comment: This is  nice to have in my back pocket, thanks.

Comment: Wow, I enjoyed writing that, but I had lost track of it. It's nice to see it again.

Comment: But at the end where it says "Prop 1"it should say "Lemma 2".

Comment: It seems like Goodwillie UQF's might coincide with Hopkins/Rezk 'sharp maps' (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9811038.pdf)